# How to map workspace and get latest folders in c#

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, tfs-sdk

It is my first time to work with TFS and I am not quite familiar how workspace mapping works. I would just like to print the local folder and repository folder when the workspace is mapped, so I would know if the workspace is mapped because I get an exception such as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
var workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(path);
var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(workspaceInfo.ServerUri);
var workspace = workspaceInfo.GetWorkspace(server);
workspace.PendEdit(path);
```

And is my Get Latest code correct? I mean I would like to get the latest version of a whole folder and this is what I got.

```
var service = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
var getLatestOfTfsRepositoryCs = service.GetWorkspace(@"C:\temp\project");
```

Comment: Where do you get that exception - which line of code specifically?  Does `path` have a workspace mapped to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use  `Workspace.IsLocalPathMapped` method in order to check

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.islocalpathmapped.aspx

If you wish get lastest version you can use `Workspace.Get` method, with `VersionSpec.Latest value`

Comment: If a folder is mapped, it means that everything inside it is mapped right? If I would want to get latest just a specific folder, for example C:\temp is mapped and I wanted to get latest C:\temp\projects\source (just the "source" folder only), that's possible right?

Comment: 1. yes if folder mapped so all files are mapped correctly, 2. yes it's possible with same hierarchy between source control and workspace